# Why React Dropzone Uploader doesn't reload until I change something from the code?

Tags: reactjs, file-upload

I am using React Dropzone Uploader and everything looks good. But after I select the file, I couldn't see the preview of the selected file until I change something from the code and when I click on close button, because it doesn't automatically render the change the selected file keeps rendering on the page, but they're closed behind the scene. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I have tried to use useEffect on the Dropzone. But it didn't work